# How to implement JS client-side page cache?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, local-storage, browser-cache

I need to add a client-side cache for the web application, as the site oriented on mobile devices with not so high response and connection speed. Is there any "best practices" for the front-end caching?

Rails 3 is used for the backend, JS+jQuery for the frontend.

I want to change as least as possible. Perfect option is to load a page from the cache and then re-load it from the backend if page was updated.

It is an option to use something like backbone or knockout to develop front-end application with only data retrieving from the backend, but I wan't to avoid routing, views and logic transfer to the front end if it is possible for the moment.

Comment: *Easiest* would be to specify an expires header for your HTML content. Give it something like a day or so, so individual user session will be fast. The trade-off is that they may not instantly see any updates you make on the site.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is data updates really often (measurements from sensors), and it should be gathered by backend from the other server via API. Regular HTML cache just is not ok, and I need user to see the old page while requests travel back and forward (which takes time for the mobile device+API).